# Integrate a column using integrate.trapz with datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

Good morning,

I have the follwing code to determine the integral of a column using the trapez method :

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import integrate

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = ['29/07/2021', '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '29/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021',   '30/07/2021']
df['Time'] = ['06:48:37',   '06:59:37', '07:14:37', '07:27:44', '07:42:44', '07:57:44', '08:04:32', '08:19:32', '09:01:20', '09:19:06', '09:49:06', '10:09:01', '10:23:31', '10:39:18', '10:54:17', '11:09:17', '11:20:01', '11:35:01', '11:50:00', '11:54:14', '12:09:14', '12:22:01', '12:30:15', '12:45:15', '13:00:15', '13:40:15', '13:55:15', '14:10:15', '14:27:15', '14:42:15', '14:57:15', '15:12:15', '15:27:15', '15:42:15', '15:57:15', '16:12:15', '08:12:50', '08:42:50', '08:57:50', '09:12:50', '09:42:50', '09:57:50', '10:12:50', '10:27:50', '10:42:50', '10:57:50', '11:12:50', '11:27:50', '11:42:50', '11:57:50', '12:12:50', '12:27:50', '12:42:50', '12:57:50', '13:12:50', '13:31:48', '13:43:25', '15:15:20', '15:24:44', '15:34:44', '15:39:03', '15:45:28', '15:55:28', '16:05:28', '16:15:28', '16:25:28', '16:35:28', '16:45:28', '16:55:28', '17:05:28', '17:15:28', '17:25:28', '17:35:28', '17:45:28', '17:55:28', '18:05:28', '18:15:28', '18:25:28']
df['Column1'] = [0.01153489116, 0.01345839865,  0.01779293663,  0.0188075811,   0.02593143441,  0.02516351682,  0.02656128256,  0.02774365902,  0.01068687582,  0.0492178287,   0.03830963094,  0.03982806424,  0.01197452205,  0.0452324925,   0.056356989,    0.057672,   0.06444093731,  0.01257135768,  0.0293379174,   0.01347513612,  0.03167956869,  0.03127426809,  0.0561366325,   0.04949798985,  0.0480188952,   0.0357266179,   0.01970254124,  0.01941959216,  0.01782295605,  0.01299120592,  0.0269445306,   0.01212425752,  0.01330537192,  0.00983425672,  0.0101417148,   0.02101192236,  0.01781862992,  0.00758453253,  0.0076804071,   0.00922775574,  0.0073747856,   0.00853069657,  0.03282369543,  0.02961645624,  0.03013929116,  0.010247364,    0.03243998824,  0.01806667814,  0.0325989132,   0.03179977488,  0.03362982444,  0.0094431753,   0.0082718999,   0.0109086495,   0.04043482872,  0.01571583463,  0.0573673107,   0.03165296424,  0.02008226187,  0.01864084944,  0.02020784928,  0.00982873458,  0.00791156214,  0.0123223301,   0.0067242825,   0.00775056588,  0.004625349911, 0.003382658468, 0.0075472771,   0.006104127873, 0.01520061243,  0.00891038148,  0.0069686624,   0.006432309,    0.00254625114,  0.003212563191, 0.00237200964,  0.001625559964]
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
dp = df.set_index('DateTime')
dp['Column2'] = dp['Column1'].rolling('1D').apply(integrate.trapz)
print(dp['Column2'].head(1000))
```

It is working, but the problem is that the trapez method is like this for a range on the x-axis [a, b]:

**(b - a) * (f(b) + f(a) / 2)**

and if we consider many points inside the range [a, b], it will be the **'sum' of (f(b) + f(a) / 2)** which we multiple afterwards with **(b - a)**.

The code is doing the sum, but he is not multiplying by the time difference in the index which is the datetime.

Would you please give me a hint on why it's not doing that ? Thank you.

**PS** : take as example the first two points : (0.01153489116 + 0.01345839865)/2 = 0,012496644905 which is exactly the 2nd value that you will see in the print so it's not multiplying by the datetime difference in index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the index as second argument to `integrate.trapz` in order for it to be able to compute the integral.

```
dp['Column1'].rolling('1D').apply(lambda x : integrate.trapz(x,x.index))
```

Which results in

```
|DateTime            |Column1       |
|--------------------|--------------|
|2021-07-29 06:48:37 |  0.000000e+00|
|2021-07-29 06:59:37 |  8.247786e+09|
|2021-07-29 07:14:37 |  2.231089e+10|
|     ...            |      ...     |
|2021-07-30 18:25:28 |  7.380168e+11|
```

However I don't see the use of such an integral between to points that are a day apart. If you are interested in a cumulative integral I would suggest using

```
df['integral'] = ((df.DateTime-df.DateTime.shift(1))*\
                 ((df.Column1+df.Column1.shift(1))/2))[1:].cumsum()
```

which results in the same dataframe in the beginning but keeps integrating

[image: Comparison of integral results]

Or if what you are looking for with `rolling('1D')` is to compute the Integral for each day separately, then you could use

```
dp['Column1'].resample('d').apply(lambda x : integrate.trapz(x,x.index))
```

Which results in

```
DateTime
2021-07-29   0 days 00:16:19.051562019
2021-07-30   0 days 00:12:18.016804347
Freq: D, Name: Column1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. For the first two solutions i don't think that's what i'm looking for because it's just the time in nano second. The last line is about computing on a day and yes it is what i want but it is not having the exact value, if you calculate the sum for the day 2021-07-29 you will find 0.272. My code is doing for each timestamp an integral but without multiplying by the timestamp difference it is just doing the (f(b) + f(a)) / 2

Comment: Im sorry but I don't follow lets consider the first value  (b-a)(f(b) + f(a)) / 2 = 11*60s*0.012 = 8.2e9 ns which is correct. Also the integral values for the days are correct, I double checked.

Comment: i'm ok with 0.012 (precisely 0,012496644905) but the time difference is 06:59:37 - 06:48:37 which is exactly 0.183333 hours (it's better for me to have it in hours) so it will be 0.01249 * 0.18333 = 0,0022897917 and that is the value i'm looking for for the first one

Comment: Then simply transform the nanosenconds into hours (divide by 3.6e12), the result is still valid. 8.2e9/3.6e12 = 0.002277

Comment: Yeah my brain is down i guess all day working got me off xD. Thank you very much i hope you'll have the best in your life ! PS : I validated your response as solution.

Comment: can you tell me if it is possible to not add up the values while rolling ? for example the 2nd value should be 0.0039 (using hours transformation) but instead i get 0.0062 which is 0.0022 (first value) + 0.0039 (second value)